# React Typescript: @types/react-router-dom vs react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript and using it the first time on React project. I am really confusing about @types npm packages. Could you please tell me the difference between, `@types/react-router-dom` and `react-router-dom` and which package should be used?

Thanks!

Comment: @types/whatever is a package that gives you the typings for the whatever package. `react-router-dom` is the actual library, the other gives the types for TS

Answer (score 2):

**react-router-dom** - *required* - actual package
**@types/react-router-dom** - *optional* - adds typings for typescript project

as Li357 noted: ***@types/whatever*** is a package that gives you the typings for the whatever package for typescript project

Answer (score -1):

**install @types/react-router-dom**- this package has built-in type declarations. You can use those type definitions in your code.

Comment: Looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: okay, You can give an answer, I'll learn from you.

Comment: I meant, I think your post doesn't answer the question. For example, look at [Medet Tleukabiluly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308005/medet-tleukabiluly)'s answer.

Comment: Certainly, I need to learn , how to give answers

Comment: Your answer appeared in Stackoverflow's *Review queues*, I had to do some action to help with first answer. Sorry, if I offended you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) may be helpful.

Comment: Nothing to offend sir, I am here to learn.